# sortable not working on popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, bootstrap-modal, knockout-sortable

I am facing an issue in drag drop functionality between multiple lists in a popup when there are so many items in list 1.

I'm using knockout-sortable.js and modal popup.

`<div class="seats" data-bind="sortable: { data: students }">`

I've modified the seating chart example. Here's the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/e15qrdcw/) for knockout-sortable.js.

Same issue occurs with sortable using jquery-ui.

Here's the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/rmbv6shy/) for jquery-ui.js.

Here, if I scroll down to the last name(Lyla) in the first list and drag it in the second empty list, drop doesnot happen. However, if I scroll the names in the top of list, where I don't have to scroll upward (Bobby, Ted, Jim, etc), the item drops in the second list.

This issue doesnot occur without popup.

Please help.

In this case, I have to drag the item to the empty list first and then drop it. I should not drag it to the top of the first list and then drop it in the second list.

Comment: It seems like it fails to recognize that it's entered a new dropzone when it auto-scrolls while you're dragging. If you drag up to the empty list, then drag over to the first list, then back to the empty list, it becomes droppable.

Comment: But in my requirement, I really need to drag to the empty list first. Any suggestions for the fix? Or some references?

Comment: I understand my comment wasn't a solution, just a data point. You don't have to drop the item into the first column, only hover over it to get the drop zone detection to activate. Then continue to drag it over into the empty list.
In fact, if you drag straight up the first list, you'll see drop-zone activation all the way up. Then at the top, drag over to the second column.

Comment: I found out that this problem occurs with jquery-ui.js sortable also. The issue is with popup only. Let me know if you find something.